# How to catch facebook share button id?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Hey guys How can I catch facebook share button id? I mean this page share button(http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php? ) Not counter share button

I use this function but it doesnt work..

function fbs_click() {

```
                   u = location.href;
                   t = document.title;
                   neww = window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(u) + '&t=' + encodeURIComponent(t), 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');

                   $(neww.document).ready(function () {

                       $(".uiButtonConfirm input[name='share']").mouseover(function () {

                           alert("test");

                       });


                   });

             return false;


               }
```

Comment: I have edited My first message check it please!

Answer (score 1):

You can't access another page like this. The `neww` window is on another domain (facebook.com) and cross-domain policies won't allow you to run javascript on this page because it is on another domain. This includes listening for an element in another window to be hovered over.

I can have a guess that what you want to do is some kind of feedback when the user shares using this sharer.php page? If so, the only thing I can recommend is to have some kind of feedback when the user closes this share or `neww` window. You would do this by adding the following after you open the window:

```
neww.onunload = function(){ 
    // Do what you want to do when the window has closed
    alert("CLOSED!!"); 
}
```